# One-Tap verification fails at SmsBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, sms

I am trying to make the one-tap verification work in an example app (https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/overview?hl=en).

Currently I do not receive an SMS call in the onReceive of my BroadCastReceiver:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    object Constants {
        const val RESOLVE_HINT = 0
        const val CREDENTIAL_PICKER_REQUEST = 1
        const val SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST = 2
    }

    private val smsVerificationReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION == intent.action) {
                val extras = intent.extras
                val smsRetrieverStatus = extras?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status

                when (smsRetrieverStatus.statusCode) {
                    CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                        // Get consent intent
                        val consentIntent = extras.getParcelable<Intent>(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT)
                        try {
                            // Start activity to show consent dialog to user, activity must be started in
                            // 5 minutes, otherwise you'll receive another TIMEOUT intent
                            startActivityForResult(consentIntent, SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST)
                        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                            // Handle the exception ...
                        }
                    }
                    CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                        // Time out occurred, handle the error.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val intentFilter = IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)
        registerReceiver(
            smsVerificationReceiver,
            intentFilter,
            SmsRetriever.SEND_PERMISSION,
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        )

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        startSMSRetreiver(this)
    }

    private fun startSMSRetreiver(activity: Activity) {
        val smsRetreiver = SmsRetriever.getClient(activity)
        smsRetreiver.startSmsUserConsent("+1 650 555-6789")
        // +1-555-521-5554 Emulator Phone Number
        // +1 650 555-6789 Sender Number
        // pass null if you want to select a phone number
    }

    // Obtain the phone number from the result
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST ->
                // Obtain the phone number from the result
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    // Get SMS message content
                    val message = data.getStringExtra(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE)
                    // Extract one-time code from the message and complete verification
                    // `message` contains the entire text of the SMS message, so you will need
                    // to parse the string.
                    val oneTimeCode = parseOneTimeCode(message) // define this function

                    // send one time code to the server
                } else {
                    // Consent denied. User can type OTC manually.
                }
        }
    }

    private fun parseOneTimeCode(message: String?): String? {
        return message
    }
}
```

As you can see I want to try it out with the emulator, where you can send SMS to yourself conveniently. My problem is that after starting the app and sending myself an SMS, I do not receive a call in the BroadcastReceiver. I am not sure if I setup my Receiver correctly, also maybe the PhoneNumber is not correct (does is have a specific format?). Maybe I am missing something else.

My goal is to not use additional Permissions in the Manifest, receive the SMS code and parse it / pass it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some deeper debugging and found out, that if I check the success of

```
smsRetreiver.startSmsUserConsent(null).addOnSuccessListener {
                    println("SmsUserConsent success")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    println("SmsUserConsent failure: $it")
                }
```

it fails on the emulator with `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: SmsRetriever.API is not available on this device. Connection failed`

Maybe this is fixable with some setup of the emulator or some proxy settings that I am missing, but on my real device the code works. Hope this can help someone, if you got questions, feel free!

Comment: Note to my past self: It is indeed fixable if you install an emulator with the PlayStore installed -> this emulator has the Google Play Services that you need to use the SMSConsent in this way.